# Captive Portal and HTTPS Redirect

Tags: javascript, http, https, openwrt, portal

So I am having a little bit of trouble with two elements of redirection on my router. So when a user connects to the router, I wanted my home page to auto-pop up like when you connect to airport wifi. Additionally, I wanted any search to return my home page. I successfully accomplished both of these tasks by adding two lines to my dnsmasq.conf file.

```html
address=/myssid.local/my.ip.add.ress
address=/#/my.ip.add.ress
```

However, I am having two issues. The first is that it will only redirect http requests and not https. For example, http://www.google.com returns my home page, but https://www.google.com returns an error. Is there a way to solve this problem? I also was hoping to find a way to redirect users from the captive portal that pops up on Apple and Android products, because the captive portal's javascript limitation is hindering my project. I wanted to have a simple button on the captive portal that redirects users from the captive portal to a web browser. I have tried a variety of attempts to create the "success" page to force Apple's CNA to close. However, all of these attempts have resulted in nothing being opened when users connect to the wifi through an Apple product.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do anything about the https issue: Part of https is the assertion that you're connected to the correct communication partner, and not a man in the middle (e.g. a captive portal)

And in HTTP, you can't redirect to a particular application. It's up to the browser how it handles any link. And http links will typically be handled by that application itself. If you have a particular app that registers for a protocol or a specific URL or MIME type, you might be able to get a question (e.g. like opening an RSS feed), but it's no guarantee that either your app is installed, or no other app handles the same protocol.

Plus, IMHO captive portals are only another word for "broken internet". But that's just a closing thought. Don't invest too much time into it: The more sites go https only, the less useful a captive portal will be.